# Get data from Salesforce using webAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, salesforce

I am trying to create a middleware between SAP and Salesforce. It is a .NET RESTful service.

If SAP desires any data, it will pass parameters to my .NET API which in turn will query Salesforce for the same. It should fetch the data and return as XML to SAP.

My first step is to build a webAPI and fetch sample data (about 10-20 rows) from Salesforce developer account.

I referred to Salesforce documentation on how to setup Remote Access for external applications which uses oAuth. The Remote Access documentation page looks a bit obsolete.

I want to know whether I need to enable Remote Access first in Salesforce and expose endpoints for my .NET Service to consume it? Where can I find updated Remote Access oAuth documentation for interacting with the .NET webAPI?

The link I referred is this: [Consuming Force.com SOAP and REST Web Services from .NET Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications)

Comment: Why are you using middle ware as opposed to the Salesforce SAP connector?

Comment: The preliminary requirement itself is this. Is there any way to directly connect Salesforce to SAP? Query will be sent from SAP and Salesforce should return the result.

Comment: well it's not a connector, but salesforce lightning connect which lets you see SAP data in salesforce, depending on the use case and in recent releases you can now update the data in salesforce and it saves to SAP see https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/salesforce-1-lightning-connect-sap-step-step.html.  But the documentation you referenced is accurate but I would use the JWT OAuth flow as opposed to the username password flow

Comment: That's a wonderful link and it should serve the purpose. But in case I want to consume my .NET API in salesforce, what to do? How should I consume and pass updated data to this API parameter? Any link on this?

Comment: If you want to consume your .net api in salesforce (i.e. from Salesforce make a call to your api) you can do this in apex code, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm.  But if this is to get data from salesforce into your .net application there are other easier ways.  You should look at Outbound Messages where you can use workflow to send information to a soap endpoint , it also has automatic retries built in.